# Issues with image swap via jquery and sizing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to swap images via `jquery` using this function and everything is fine:

```
$(function(){
    $(".highlight").hover(
        function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");},
        function(){this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
    });
});
```

Except for one thing. The default image (image with _off suffix) resorts back to a smaller size for some reason. Why is this? I was thinking that the `jquery` function nulled the `css` styling attributes on the image that I am swapping out.

Comment: Not likely. Can we see your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Or post a fiddle to demonstrate the effect